# How to properly parse out error code from lambda response in openapi api-gateway

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am setting up an endpoint for a lambda in api-gateway using openapi. This lambda will need to be be able to return `400/500` error codes for internal errors/bad requests. To this end I have tried to format the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` section of the openapi json document for this endpoint as follows:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
    ...
    "responses": {
        ".*statusCode\\\":400.*": {
            "statusCode": "400",
            "responseTemplates": {
                "application/json": "#set ($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage'))) \n{ \"message\" : \"$errorMessageObj.message\"}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The raw output from my lambda (i.e. before transformations) looks like this:

```
"{\"statusCode\":400,\"message\":\"Invalid request parameters\"}"
```

My expectation would be that the final response would have an error code of `400` and the object returned to my client would be

```
{
    "message": "Invalid request parameters"
}
```

But I am getting the full untransformed response object back with a response code of 200 (the default). I have referenced this [aws-blog-post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) which towards the bottom has the regex I am attempting to use. It passes a [regex-parser](https://regexr.com/4n5au) So I am not understanding why I am still getting the default response back. I am using openapi v3. What is is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the lambda you need to throw an error with the response code you want parsed out. If you simply return it assumes correct execution.